# Decompositions via Invariant Subspaces

Tags: modules, linear-transformations, jordan-normal-form

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, and let $T: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation such that $T^{4} - I = T^{3} + 3T^{2} + T + 3 =0$. Prove that $V$ is a direct sum of $2$-dimensional $T$-invariant subspaces.

$T$ satisfies: $f(x) = (x-1)(x+1)(x^{2} + 1)$ and $g(x) = (x + 3)(x^{2} + 1)$. Hence, the minimal polynomial of $T$ must divide both $f$ and $g$ and it follows that $m_{T}(x) = x^{2} + 1$.

I know that $V = \mathbb{R}^{\dim V} = \bigoplus_{i = 1}^{r}\mathbb{R}[x]/(p_{i}(x))$, where $p_{i}|p_{i+1}$ and the largest of these is $m_{T}(x)$ and since $m_{T}(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$, $p_{i} = x^{2} + 1$ for all $i$.

**If I can conclude that the dimension of $V$ is $4$, then I am done as then there will be only another invariant factor, which must be also equal to the minimal polynomial.**

Another way one could proceed is to invoke the primary decomposition to write $\ker (T + 3I) \oplus \ker (T^{2} + I) = V = \ker (T-I) \oplus \ker (T+I) \oplus \ker (T^{2} + I)$.

Comment: You cannot conclude $V$ is $4$-dimensional (over $\mathbb R$). Counter-example take $V=\mathbb C^r$,(any $r$, say $1$) as $\mathbb R$ vs, and take $T$ to be multiplication by $i$. Each $\mathbb C$ is clearly $T$ invariant  (and irreducible).... But why don't you think you are done? You have in fact exhibited $V$ as the desired decomposition - no?

Comment: You are correct. My entire effort was being wasted because I misread the problem. I thought they were saying two subspaces each of dimension 2:-)